# Run app and launch browser from command line

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, command-line-interface, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to start my app from the command line and automatically start a browser and show a default page (as it is run from IDE). I tried with this command:

```
dotnet run --launch-profile "MyApp"
```

In My app launchSettings.json I have defined:

```
"MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53348/"
}
```

But the browser does not start.

Comment: I don't think dotnet can start a browser. It will just start the server and use the `applicationUrl` and environment variables but will not start the browser.

Comment: If its only required on Windows OS, use System.Diagnostics.Process() with command 'start app-url' 'start' is built-in command. ex: 'start http://google.com'

Comment: As I run my app from batch file I can start browser after app is run.

Comment: Yes its similar to batch file idea, but with System.Diagnostics.Process() you don't need batch file, it will be embedded, if that's works for you, I can provide answer with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in this case it is possible to run two programs in a batch file one after another, and this would solve a case.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, you can combine the two commands into a single line:

```
dotnet run --launch-profile MyApp | start chrome http://localhost:5000
```